# Use VectorDrawables in a Bitmap XML and tint them

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-vectordrawable

We are trying to move all our app icon resources to VectorDrawables to reduce the size of the app and manage the app icon kit easily.

We already have an Icon Kit with all the icons of our app, all in a black color and the idea is to use them and tint in each usage with the appropriate color. This works (more or less) perfectly until you try to made the same in a `layer-list`/`selector`/similar, where you need to include an item with a `<bitmap>` or similar and... I don't find how to tint a `VectorDrawable` that also works in <21 devices

The pre-requisite is to not need to make it programmatically, I know that is possible but made it programmatically breaks all the easy usage of the icons and, also, not has sense.

In resume, Is there any form to use `VectorDrawable` in a `<Bitmap>` XML and tint it working in <21 devices and not programmatically?

Comment: I added this Feature request to Android issue tracker, feel free to start it
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62369594

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer: No, you can't do that.

The extended version:

Copy the SVG and apply color:

```
icon_a.xml
icon_b.xml (with color changed)
```

Comment: Nice one @alorma, sadly this is the only solution for the moment. But is a lot better to has multiple version of the same SVG resource than PNGs for each density. Hope Android team allow us to use SVG everywhere once for all.

Comment: I added this Feature request to Android issue tracker, feel free to start it issuetracker.google.com/issues/62369594

Comment: Fixed link mentioned in comment above: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62369594